# How to compare a value stored in Firebase in a if statement?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been searching and looking for an answer everywhere for days and still can't figure this out.

First let me show you what i want to achieve, here is the picture of the program:
[image]

And here is the picture of my Firestore database:
[image]

I want to be able and check if the user puts in the roomID in this case 5575 like in the picture above, the program should first check if that roomID exists in the firestore database. When i click the button Join i dont get anything in the console.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
const name12 = document.getElementById("oponentname") ;
const roomid = document.getElementById("idinput");
const joinButton = document.getElementById("joinButton");

var firebaseConfig = {

my configuration is here

}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();


joinButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if (roomid.value == db.collection('game').doc(roomid.value).get()) {
        console.log("Succes");
    }
    

    

});
```

Comment: You don't have any code here that writes the database, so I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: i have done that part in another JS file and i can write successfully into the databse. The only thing that I need now is how to compare the input from the input field with the roomid value in the database

Comment: get() returns a promise.  It does not return data directly.  Follow the instructions in the documentation to learn how to get a document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: I have read the instructions there but I still can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should fix it like this:

```
db.collection("game")
    .doc(roomid.value)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

You can read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web)

Comment: I keep getting this error with your solution: CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path.

Comment: It does not recognize the roomid.value , idk why

Comment: I found the error, silly me. In the HTML file where i created the input text I had to give it a default value. Thats why i kept getting that error because it was empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have to query for documents with that roomID and then check if one matches.

```
const get_room = (id) => {
    return db.collection('game')
        .doc(id)
        .get()
        .then(function(doc) {
            return doc.exists 
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

Note that this is an async function, so to check if the inputed room id exists you should use a promise or async/await. My implementation uses promises.

```
joinButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    get_room(roomid.value).then((doc) => { if (doc) console.log("Succes"); })
});
```